# Estimate the number of states in a DFA (intersection)

Tags: intersection, finite-automata, dfa

I'm having trouble understanding how to estimate the number of states in the intersection of two DFA's (M1 and M2, which have n and k states). I don't want to construct an actual DFA, but to understand how many states an intersection will give. For example, the union of M1 and M2 will give |n| x |k| states (if I have understood this correctly). Is there anyone who could help me understand this problem? I have some difficulty understanding DFA's...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given two DFAs D<sub>1</sub> and D<sub>2</sub> with n<sub>1</sub> and n<sub>2</sub> states, respectively, it's possible to construct a new DFA D<sub>3</sub> with n<sub>1</sub>n<sub>2</sub> states in it whose language is the intersection of the languages of D<sub>1</sub> and D<sub>2</sub> by using the product construction: have the states of D correspond to pairs of states, one from D<sub>1</sub> and one from D<sub>2</sub>, and where the accepting states correspond to pairs of accepting states from D<sub>1</sub> and D<sub>2</sub>.

That said, this isn't necessarily going to be the minimum-state DFA for the intersection. It's just going to be *some* DFA for the intersection.